# JSP view manipulation onFocusOut - Framework Spring MVC

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, event-handling, jsp-tags

I am using Spring MVC framework and my view components are JSP.

I have several input fields in view

[image: Input fields]

All these input fields have corresponding Total fields which should display the total of the amount in fields

[image: Total field]

How do I trigger a function to calculate total when data is entered and focus is lost from input field.

I am using custom tag for input fields

```
<e:numberInput target='${formBean.amounts}[${counter.index}].price'
  editable="false"
   cssClass="input-field"
/>
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by adding onchange HTML attribute to my custom tag.

Answer (score -1):

This is what you can do

```
<e:numberInput target='${formBean.amounts}[${counter.index}].price'
  editable="false" class = "amount"
   cssClass="input-field"
/>
```

Use JQuery/Javascript to add up the amount during lost focus. Hope this helps.